# Encrypting code with GPG

Tags: encryption, gnupg, openpgp

I want to encrypt a code I wrote.
After a quick search, I have found recommendation on GPG.

Is encrypting code with GPG common and standard? I have read that it is supposed to be for e-mails.
If not GPG, what should I use?

Comment: Are you talking about protecting an archive of your source code or encrypting the binary?  If you're talking about the binary you're headed the wrong direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPG for signing, encrypting, and decrypting texts, e-mails, files, directories, and whole disk.

But the common way to secure your code is code **obfuscation** and not encryption.

[Obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) creates ambiguous code, which makes reverse engineering difficult.

You can use spacial obfuscator for your programming language which is a programming tool that is used to transform readable code into ambiguous code without affecting code functionality.